# Highcharts - Change column color If data.point equal to string

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am creating a column type graph. Is there a way in javascript to change the color(which I want to define) of a column IF Gait == Walk

Here is an example of the graph im working on
https://jsfiddle.net/NRKSensors/4t6q5z0j/3/

```js
$(function() {
  Highcharts.setOptions({
    colors: ['#ffffff', '#000000', '#666666']
  });

  var chart, merge = Highcharts.merge;
  $(document).ready(function() {



    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'column',
        zoomType: 'x  ',
        marginTop: 20,
        borderColor: null,
        borderRadius: 20,
        borderWidth: 2,
        backgroundColor: null,
      },
      title: {
        text: null
      },

      subtitle: {
        text: null
      },

      data: {
        csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML,
        seriesMapping: [{
          x: 0, // Insert X values in minutes
          y: 1, // Insert Y values (Frequency)
          label: 2 // Insert Labels (Standing,Walk, Trot, Canter, Jump)
        }]
      },

      tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        formatter: function() {
          point = this.point;
          html = '<table>';
          html += point.label + '</h3></th></tr>';
          html += '</table>';
          return html;
        },
        followPointer: true,
        hideDelay: 200
      },



      exporting: {
        buttons: {
          contextButton: {
            enabled: false
          }
        }
      }, // Gemmer Export Menu knappen. Den tror jeg ikke vi skal anvende.
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },

      series: [{
        type: 'column',
        color: 'black'
      }],

    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>

<pre id="csv" style="display:none">Touchdown,Frequency,Gait 
                            22.414,100,"Walk"
                            22.42366667,100,"Walk"
                            22.43333333,103.4482759,Walk
                            22.44266667,96.77419355,Walk
                            22.45266667,96.77419355,Walk                     
                            24.69466667,136.3636364,Trot
                            24.70166667,125,Trot
                            24.70933333,136.3636364,Trot
                            24.71633333,120,Trot
                            24.72433333,130.4347826,Trot
                            25.11933333,68.18181818,Canter
                            25.13366667,88.23529412,Canter
                            25.14466667,85.71428571,Canter
                            25.156,88.23529412,Canter
                          

                        </pre>
```

Do I need to prepare the data in the last column with qoutes?, so "Walk" instead of Walk?

Below is an example i made in Matlab. So I need to make it similar to this, but in highcharts

[Matlab Column example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/365at.png)

Comment: check this is your requirement https://jsfiddle.net/5ctegyzs/1/ .if this ok, I will add answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is to add a new column called color and set the value of this column based on the value of "Gait". This would be done in after highcharts have parsed the csv data like this:

```
data: {
  csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML, // Delete this line
  seriesMapping: [{
    x: 0, // Insert X values in minutes
    y: 1, // Insert Y values (Frequency)
    label: 2, // Insert Labels (Standing,Walk, Trot, Canter, Jump) NOT in quotes '' !!!
    color: 3 //specify that column 3 is color
  }],
  parsed: function(columns) {
    columns.push(['Color'])                        //Add a new column, color
    for (var i = 0; i < columns[2].length; i++) {
      if (columns[2][i] == 'Walk') {
        columns[3].push('Red');                    //Set color red for walk
      } else if (columns[2][i] == 'Trot') {
        columns[3].push('Blue');
      } else if (columns[2][i] == 'Canter') {
        columns[3].push('green');
      } else {                                     //Set grey for any gaits not found
        columns[3].push('grey');
      }
    }
  }
},
```

**Working example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/4t6q5z0j/40/

**API on data.parsed:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.parsed

Comment: Thank you ewolden. great help
I have e follow up question if you are up for it.

Sometimes I have above 1000 data rows. How could I use your code when also using the turboThreshold: 0 to load larger quantity of datasets.
Is it possible to use the data.parsed when using turboThreshold?

Comment: [Edit] I see that Deep 3015 code actually handles this with turboThreshold